# Many to Many field added to the profile does not work - django-userena

Tags: python, django

I am using `django-userena`. I've added manytomanyfield and gender field in UserProfile. These fields are appearing in admin UI (and can be saved and edited there) but not in templates. `Gender` and `language` fields are missing. Will you please help?! Thanks

Here is [admin screesnhot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hTTl.png) and here is my [user profile form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puu19.jpg)

Here is my `UserProfile` model

```
optional = dict(blank=True, null=True)

class UserProfile(UserenaBaseProfile):
    MALE = 1
    FEMALE = 2
    SEX_CHOICES = (
        (MALE,'Male'),
        (FEMALE,'Female'),
    )

    user = models.OneToOneField(User,
                                unique=True,
                                verbose_name=_('user'),
                                related_name='user_profile')
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,**optional)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,**optional)
    test = models.CharField(max_length=100,**optional)
    gender = models.IntegerField(choices = SEX_CHOICES,**optional)
    language = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
```

Comment: Can you show us what you do in your template? Probably also your view if it's yours...

Comment: @lazerscience I've not changed anything in template. I'm just using this url `http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/<username>/edit/`